# TFS application tier, error adding user

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, admin, administration

I'm trying to add another user (from another domain...) to the administration console users and the procedure fails when trying to add the account to the master database.

The relevant part of the log is:

> Starting Node: ADDSYSTEMDBACCOUNT
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.223] NodePath : ADDCOLLACCOUNT/ADDSYSTEMDBACCOUNT
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.223] Adding account to system databases ...
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.223] Adding account to master database ...
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.223] ModifyExecRole: Add:DEV\helis
>
> [Error  @07:21:43.363] Failed adding DEV\helis to master.
>
> [Error  @07:21:43.363] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot alter the role 'TFSEXECROLE', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException ex, QueryExecutionState queryState)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(Exception exception)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlSecurityComponent.ModifyExecRole(String accountName, String role, AccountsOperation operation)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureAddAccountToSystemDBs.AddToDatabase(ActivityContext context, SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder, String dbAccount)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureAddAccountToSystemDBs.Run(ActivityContext context)
>   ClientConnectionId:44abd1a3-fc86-4bf5-ac58-f5ef9a7a1d08
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Node returned: Error
>
> [Error  @07:21:43.363]
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Completed AddAccountToSystemDBs: Error
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] -----------------------------------------------------
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Execution results:
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Overall result: Failure
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Nodes completed: 2
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Nodes succeeded: 1
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Nodes skipped: 0
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Nodes with errors: 1
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Nodes with warnings: 0
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Number of error messages: 2
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Number of warning messages: 0
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Number of info messages: 0
>
> [Error  @07:21:43.363] Activity failed.
>
> [Info   @07:21:43.363] Activity failed and there is no handling of the failure such as rollback

I'm using a user with administrator privileges on this server so I think it's a permission problem.

**EDIT:**
The TFS is installed on a machine(DEV-LOCAL) that was not part of the domain(DEV). The machine is now part of the domain. I.E. when looking at the computer's properties it shows computer name as "DEV-LOCAL" and full computer name as "DEV-LOCAL.DEV.local". Domain name: "DEV.local"

Any idea?

Comment: Does the domain where the TFS is hosted trust the Dev domain? Are you able to add an user of the TFS domain as admin console user?

Comment: @MikeR I've edited the question with further details.

Comment: So TFS was not in another domain before, it was in a workgroup. No idea what effect that has on permissions for user of a domain. Is it possible for you to add DEV-user to TFS groups (e.g. contributors)? Is your account you are using sysadmin on the SQL server?

Comment: @MikeR Thanks Mike! That was it... The sysadmin permission in the SQL server was missing. If you post it as answer, I will accept ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To alter roles in SQL Server you need to have the sysadmin role.

Comment: Thanks Mike, now I've encountered a new problem - TF55038: You don't have sufficient privileges to run this tool. Contact your Team Foundation system administrator...

Comment: Run the command line as administrator.  (http://blog.hinshelwood.com/microsoft-please-help-me-diagnose-tfs-administration-permission-issues/)